# How to resolve this Error for custom api error message .If i remove both method of this class then project run without error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm getting this error message:

> Error creating bean with name 'handlerExceptionResolver' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver]: Factory method 'handlerExceptionResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException]: {public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.Internity.extraservice.CustomRestExceptionHandler.handleMethodArgumentNotValid(org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException,org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders,org.springframework.http.HttpStatus,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest), public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest) throws java.lang.Exception}

I'm using this code:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestControllerAdvice
public class CustomRestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{


   @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
   protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
     MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, 
     HttpHeaders headers, 
     HttpStatus status, 
     WebRequest request) {
       List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();
       for (FieldError error : ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors()) {
           errors.add(error.getField() + ": " + error.getDefaultMessage());
       }
       for (ObjectError error : ex.getBindingResult().getGlobalErrors()) {
           errors.add(error.getObjectName() + ": " + error.getDefaultMessage());
       }
    
       CustomApiError customApiError = 
         new CustomApiError(new Date(),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), errors);
       return handleExceptionInternal(
         ex, customApiError, headers, customApiError.getStatus(), request);
    
   
 
   }


/*@ExceptionHandler({ Exception.class })
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAll(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
    CustomApiError customApiError = new CustomApiError(new Date(),HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), "error occurred");
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(
            customApiError, new HttpHeaders(), customApiError.getStatus());
}*/
}
```

Comment: That does not look like the full error message to me.  Spring will give more detail as to what has gone wrong than just say 'Error creating bean...'.  Please edit your question to include the full error message.

Comment: @LukeWoodward Now you can check full error message. I have edited question

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51991992

Comment: @Luke Woodward thanks i got answer.