# Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for MethodArgumentNotValidException and NoHandlerFoundException

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, model-view-controller, controller-advice

I have a requirement to use the NoHandlerFoundException exception handler within my global exception handler.

I was already using the MethodArgumentNotValidException handler by overriding it from the extended ResponseEntityExceptionHandler class.

Now, while running the application, I am getting this exception.

I was using the method Argument Not valid handler to handle the missing fields inside my request body.

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
> Failed to instantiate
> [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver]: Factory
> method 'handlerExceptionResolver' threw exception with message:
> Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class
> org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException]:
> {protected org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
> com.kroger.iwt.coreservice.exception.handler.GlobalExceptionHandler.handleMethodArgumentNotValid(org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException,org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders,org.springframework.http.HttpStatusCode,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest),
> public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest)
> throws java.lang.Exception}

```java
@Slf4j
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler({ NoHandlerFoundException.class })
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorListResponse> notFound(final NoHandlerFoundException exception) {
        log.error("{} {}", 404, exception.getMessage());
        ErrorListResponse errorListResponse = errorResponse("Request URI Not Found", exception);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(errorListResponse);
    }

    // @Override
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatusCode status, WebRequest request) {
        List<FieldError> errors = ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors();
        List<ErrorListResponse.ErrorDetails> errorDetails = new ArrayList<>();
        for (FieldError fieldError : errors) {
            ErrorListResponse.ErrorDetails error = new ErrorListResponse.ErrorDetails();
            error.setReason(fieldError.getDefaultMessage());
            error.setCode("BAD_REQUEST");
            error.setDatetime(new DateTimeResponse(Instant.now().toString(), "America/New_York"));
            errorDetails.add(error);
        }
        ErrorListResponse errorResponse = new ErrorListResponse();
        errorResponse.setErrors(errorDetails);
        log.error("{} {}", 400, "Multiple fields are invalid");
        return new ResponseEntity(errorResponse, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for MethodArgumentNotValidException while startup of spring boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51991992/getting-ambiguous-exceptionhandler-method-mapped-for-methodargumentnotvalidexce)

Comment: No it didn't solved it .

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatusCode status, WebRequest request) {
     }

Still getting that error Following this method overriden definition.
Note -  I am using spring boot 3.1.6

Answer (score 0):

As you are extending the `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` class and override its methods you should not use the `@ExceptionHandler` annotation.

Otherwise Spring's `org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver` will find more then one handler for the same exception class and report an error.

This is valid also for methods that just handle those exceptions. Even with a different signature and/or in a different class not extending `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`. The exceptions are listed here:

```java
@ExceptionHandler({
    HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class,
    HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException.class,
    HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException.class,
    MissingPathVariableException.class,
    MissingServletRequestParameterException.class,
    MissingServletRequestPartException.class,
    ServletRequestBindingException.class,
    MethodArgumentNotValidException.class,
    HandlerMethodValidationException.class,
    NoHandlerFoundException.class,
    NoResourceFoundException.class,
    AsyncRequestTimeoutException.class,
    ErrorResponseException.class,
    MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class,
    ConversionNotSupportedException.class,
    TypeMismatchException.class,
    HttpMessageNotReadableException.class,
    HttpMessageNotWritableException.class,
    MethodValidationException.class,
    BindException.class
})
```

**Solution**

Remove `@ExceptionHandler` annotations from the methods handling the same exceptions as in `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` (listed above). For these exceptions you should always override the handler methods and not define your own ones.

Comment: I think I got the solution
Just need to use this method definition removing headers, httpStatusCode and making argument as final worked for me. Also I need to remove the inheriting behaviour of ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.

    @ExceptionHandler({MethodArgumentNotValidException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(final MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me. Just need to use this method definition removing headers, httpStatusCode and making argument as final worked for me. Also I need to remove the inheriting behaviour of ResponseEntityExceptionHandler other wise NohandlerException instantiation will not happen.

```
@ExceptionHandler({MethodArgumentNotValidException.class})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(final MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
    List<FieldError> errors = ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors();
    List<ErrorListResponse.ErrorDetails> errorDetails = new ArrayList<>();
    for (FieldError fieldError : errors) {
        ErrorListResponse.ErrorDetails error = new ErrorListResponse.ErrorDetails();
        error.setReason(fieldError.getDefaultMessage());
        error.setCode("BAD_REQUEST");
        error.setDatetime(new DateTimeResponse(Instant.now().toString(), "America/New_York"));
        errorDetails.add(error);
    }
    ErrorListResponse errorResponse = new ErrorListResponse();
    errorResponse.setErrors(errorDetails);
    log.error("{} {}", 400, "Multiple fields are invalid");
    return new ResponseEntity(errorResponse, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}


    @ExceptionHandler({ NoHandlerFoundException.class })
public ResponseEntity<ErrorListResponse> notFound(final NoHandlerFoundException exception) {
    log.error("{} {}", 404, exception.getMessage());
    ErrorListResponse errorListResponse = errorResponse("Request URI Not Found", exception);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(errorListResponse);
}
```